# How do I search for a CSV token in another file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, csv

I'm using bash shell.  I want to parse one CSV file "A", search for that string in CSV file "B", and then output the value from the first column of the matching row in CSV file B.  So I tried

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 name col3 col4 col5
do
    echo "I got:$name|$col5"
    value=`grep ${name} /tmp/accounts_created.csv | cut -d, -f${0}`
    echo "value:$value \n"
done < ~/Downloads/all_data.csv
```

but for some reason this isn't working out, despite the fact I know there is matching data in both files.  Is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: You didn't show any sample data. You should investigate the [`join`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/join.1.html) command

Comment: The better way is to use a CSV parser.  For "small" data you might look f.i. at [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 0):

As what I'm understanding, you only need awk.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{seen[$2]=1;next} /seen[$2] ~ $0/{print $1}
' ~/Downloads/all_data.csv /tmp/accounts_created.csv
```

Comment: Does awk deal with CSV formatting?  THat is, one can't always split on a "," with CSVs since some cells may contain commas in them.

Comment: Yes, so we need sample input(s) and your expected output